# Hadoop - force task attempt to start on different node

Tags: hadoop

I submitted job to the cluster of 4 hosts, I can see that it was correctly spread among 4 nodes, 1 map task per node.

Later on, one of the node failed.

I stopped tasktracker on the failed node, added the ID of that node to excludes file and updated list of nodes with **hadoop mradmin -refreshNodes**. The failed node disappeared from list of available nodes on hadoop administration pages.

Then I started tasktracker again, updated nodes with **mradmin**, and observed that the node appeared in job tracker list again.

During the time of the node being down, hadoop re-scheduled map task execution on another node, so it started to run 2 map jobs. I've got the cluster unbalanced:

- 2 nodes were running 1 task each,
- 1 node was running 2 tasks
- and 1 node (the one I restarted) was running no tasks.

I killed the job with **hadoop job -kill-task attempt_201308010141_0001_m_000000_1** and looks like it never starts again - so I can see 3 nodes running 1 task each, 1 node with no tasks at all and 1 pending task in the list.

Am I missing something? What is the correct way of 'moving' task from one node to another one?

Answer (score 0):

Jobs keep a list of blacklisted tasktrackers (there is a global blacklist and a per job one).
I think that's why your new attempt don't start again at the end on the restarted task tracker.

You can try the commands :

```
hadoop job -unblacklist <jobid> <hostname>
hadoop job -unblacklist-tracker <hostname>
```

From http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/TaskTracker+Blacklisting